# Unparsable Date Exception: Formatting input date into a specified format

Tags: java, exception, simpledateformat

I have a date input that comes in the following form:

Unparseable date: `"Sun Jan 08 18:38:54 CST 2012"`

I am trying to use the SimpleDateFormat

```
(formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");) and chop off the time  xx:xx:xx CST piece at the end. The date should be instead: 07-01-2012.
```

How can i parse the above input date into this date format dd-MM-yy

EDIT:

```
String str_date = (String)this.studentForm.getDateOfBirth().getValue().toString();

try {
                    date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date); // exception
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: post the error you are getting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
String s = "Sun Jan 08 18:38:54 CST 2012";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");

Date d = formatter.parse(s);
String d1 = f1.format(d);
//and if you want date object create date from string d1.
```

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can create Date object from string d1

Comment: perfect. Thank you. is this how you make a Date object from d1: Date d3 = (Date) formatter.parse(d1);

Comment: yes you can convert it as you said but if you try to print d3.toString() it will show you date as Sun Jan 08 18:38:54 CST 2012.

Comment: if you try to print d3.toString() it will show you date as Sun Jan 08 18:38:54 CST 2012, because date object store all the information about time zone, hours, minutes, seconds etc. but i doubt you will need to convert it back to date. but if you do that you will always need to format it to display as dd-mm-yy.